# join data in linq if only data for object is available from view model - ASP.net -mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have viewModel that extract of multiple model classes. I am binding data and then passing to razor partial view to show data however I am getting error if one of the model object is null. In my business process it is expected however my question is can I use if condition is Linq--Joins i.e. that join result only if data exist in database or is there any better way to do it.

```
 public StudentDetailedProfileViewModel GetStudentDetailedProfileByStudentID(int _studentID)
    {
        try
        {
             using (var _uow = new StudentProfile_UnitOfWork())
            {
                 StudentDetailedProfileViewModel StudentProfileObject = new StudentDetailedProfileViewModel();

                var _profile = (from _student in _uow.Student_Repository.GetAll()
                                join _contactDetail in _uow.ContactDetail_Repository.GetAll() on _student.StudentID equals _contactDetail.StudentID
                                join _addressDetail in _uow.Address_Repository.GetAll() on _student.StudentID equals _addressDetail.StudentID
                                join _studentCourse in _uow.Course_Repository.GetAll() on _student.StudentID equals _studentCourse.StudentID
                                join _school in _uow.School_Repository.GetAll() on _studentCourse.SchoolID equals _school.SchoolID
                                join _campus in _uow.Campus_Repository.GetAll() on _studentCourse.CampusID equals _campus.CampusID
                                where _student.StudentID == _studentID
                                select new StudentDetailedProfileViewModel { _studentModel = _student, _contactDetailModel = _contactDetail, _addressModel = _addressDetail , _courseModel = _studentCourse,_schoolModel = _school, _campusModel = _campus}).FirstOrDefault();

                _profile._emergencyContactModel = (from _emergencyContact in _uow.EmergencyContact_Repository.GetAll()
                                                  where _emergencyContact.StudentID == _studentID
                                                  select _emergencyContact).ToList();


                return _profile;                
            }
        }//
        catch { return null; }

    }
```

......

```
public class StudentDetailedProfileViewModel
{
    public StudentDetailedProfileViewModel() { }

    public Student _studentModel { get; set; }
    public Course _courseModel { get; set; }
    public School _schoolModel { get; set; }
    public Campus _campusModel { get; set; }
    public ContactDetail _contactDetailModel { get; set; }
    public Address _addressModel { get; set; }
    public List<EmergencyContact> _emergencyContactModel { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of JOINing, if your root entity (Student) has navigation properties to the child collections (and the associations are configured in your entity model) you could Include() them.  Let LINQ generate the select statement rather than trying to figure it out beforehand.